# Is it possible to take SharePoint installed Azure VM image?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, azure-virtual-machine, iaas

1. Is it possible to take image of SharePoint installed Azure VM?
2. If yes, by using that image, we can create new VM which is having SharePoint?
3. If yes, is there any license problem with SharePoint? Because, SharePoint license will be having for limited system only right?

Comment: define `take`, please?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to take image of SharePoint installed Azure VM?

Yes, it is possible. More information about how to capture a VM image from a generalized Azure VM please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image).  You should  generalize your Windows virtual machine for use as an image firstly, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-generalize-vhd?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json).

> If yes, by using that image, we can create new VM which is having
>   SharePoint?

Yes, you could. Sysprep removes all your personal account information, among other things, and prepares the machine to be used as an image. But it does not delete your data.

> If yes, is there any license problem with SharePoint? Because,
>   SharePoint license will be having for limited system only right?

Every element of a SharePoint farm that is installed on Azure virtual machines must comply with the licensing requirements for SharePoint 2013 and related and supporting technologies. More information please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154957.aspx).